# Mac4.1 SL 10.6.2 Disk Utility log

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Permissions differ on "usr/share/derby", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .

> Warning: SUID file "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent" has been modified and will not be repaired.

Didn't like the look of that one so I ran repair.

Repaired "usr/share/derby".  Sweet..

> Warning: SUID file "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent" has been modified and will not be repaired.

What?...

If anyone is kind enough to share some Mac knowledge or point me in right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question:

I was using Disk Utility to do a “Verify Permission” and I got the following message:

Warning: SUID file “System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent” has been modified and will not be repaired.

It’s a known issue, and actually a bogus message.

It has been around since Mac OS X 10.5, and while it has changed for Mac OS X 10.6, the issue still arises…

“You can safely ignore this message. It is accurate, but not a cause for concern.” (Apple Support 2007-11-06 — Document No. 306925)

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1448

Warning: SUID file “System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent” has been modified and will not be repaired.

Resolution You can safely ignore these messages. You can also usually ignore any “ACL found but not expected…” message. These messages can occur if you change permissions on a file or directory. These messages are accurate but are generally not a cause for concern.